# Vue / Vuex state changes not affecting parents

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I have an input in a child component. Its value is changed there and stored in the state. The parent component uses that value for some logic. When I change the value in the child, I thought the parent would detect the state change. I'm finding only when the parent itself updates does it get the changed data.

I'm new to Vue and state management in general. I thought a state change would be reflected instantly, anywhere that variable is use, parent or child. I kind of thought state was like a ubiquitous ether and if mapped / imported into a component, would permeate everything.

Comment: Does that logic includes `Objects`?
If yes, then you might be falling into Vue's reactivity pitfalls.

Vue automatically cannot detect changes in `Objects`, there are ways to do it.
Can you add some code?

Comment: I can't say for certain without seeing how your code is set up, but maybe you'd benefit from using [`watch`ers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers). There are a few change detection caveats [mentioned in the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), if you haven't seen them. I know it took me way too long to find out that this section was in there.

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: What you described should be working, so the issue lies specifically with your code. We can't help you unless you can provide some code, or even better a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

When changing the child of an object in the Vuex store, sometimes Vue not show that correctly. I faced this issue when I try to watch the store object and some child key value of the object is changed. I solved this by making a copy of the entire object;

Declare this cloning function globally,

```
_cloneObj: function(obj){
   return JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(obj));
}
```

Now, use this function whenever changing the value in store, like

```
CHANGE_STORE: (state,newValue) =>{
   let obj =  _cloneObj(state.your_object); // this will give you clone of the store obkect
   obj.your_key = newValue; // change the value you want
   state.your_object = obj; // set the value back to store
}
```

The store will consider this as the entire object change and it'll reflect everywhere.